# MySQL/PHP Add string to cell in database using Update without overwriting

Tags: php, mysql, string, sql-update, append

I'm pretty new to MySQL and PHP, so excuse me if this question is a little silly. I'm trying to update a certain cell in my database, but I don't want the string that's already in the cell to be overwritten.

I've been practicing with this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_update

I tried the following, the append text method which would work for me in AS3 (But obviously PHP is different):

```
UPDATE Customers
SET ContactName= ContactName + 'Alfred Schmidt', City='Hamburg'
WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';
```

But instead of appending the text or even overwriting it, the ContactName cell for that customer becomes "0", I have no idea why.

My question is, is there a way to append the text in a certain cell of the database, without overwriting what's already there?

PS: I found a few questions with a similar title to mine, but none of them really did what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Use `ContactName = concat(ContactName, 'Alfred Schmidt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ContactName = concat(ContactName, 'Alfred Schmidt')
```

since `+` is a mathematical operation and MySQL tries to convert your strings to a number to do it which leads to

```
0 + 0 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly ^^  At first it wouldn't work, but that was because I was trying it in that SQL tutorial, which leads me to think that concat is a php command, and not an SQL one.